# An extra column created in a single row in a table

Tags: latex

I wanted a table in latex, and the headings to be centered both horizontally and vertically within it with more vertical space than the rest of the columns. This is the code i wrote;

```
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}\hline
   \rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large{\textsc{Vitamin}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large{\textsc{Use In Body}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large{\textsc{Deficiency Disease}}}\rule{0pt}{25pt} \rule[-25pt]{0pt}{25pt}\\\hline
   \linebreak
   &  & 
\end{tabular}
```

This is the result i get.
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg1sH.png)

There is an extra column or something that exists after the third column. Do you know any fixes random stranger?

Comment: please make a compilable [mre], including all the necessary packages etc

Comment: ive got it thanks, just needed to use multirow properly rather than throw stuff at the table and expect it to work

Comment: Yeah, using things properly is often a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the vertical rule (strut) within a column. You have defined it outside it which is causing the unexpected extensions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}\hline
      \rowcolor{lightgray}\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large{\textsc{Vitamin}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large{\textsc{Use In Body}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large{\textsc{Deficiency Disease\rule{0pt}{25pt} \rule[-25pt]{0pt}{25pt}}}}
      \\\hline
      &  & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

You can use a single `rule` instead of two like this `\rule[-25pt]{0pt}{50pt}`. Also, notice that the 1st row is not vertically centered.

I would propose you use the `tabularray` package which makes managing rows and columns very easy. Also, it's more preferred for color tables with vertical lines.

Code using the `tabularray` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec=lll,
        row{1}={c, m, 50pt, lightgray, font=\large\scshape},
    }    
        Vitamin & Use In Body & Deficiency Disease\\ 
        &&\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: I do have some questions;
For;
```row{1}={c, m, 50pt, lightgray, font=\large\scshape}```
What does 'm' do here?

For;
```colspec=lll```
What does that do? Is it just for the left alignment of columns?

Comment: `colspec` is to define column types similar to what you defined in the tabular. And `m` is for vertically centering row 1.

Comment: k thanks, bit late of reply, i saw your comment, but forgot to reply to it.

Comment: ok, did that now